# Return multiple values from a user defined function

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a dummy dataset in R with around 5000 rows and 5-6 columns. I am trying to achieve it by creating random functions for each of the columns. However calling functions returns only one value. Code by which I am trying to achieve it as follows: -

```
Vertical <- function(a) {
  vec1 <- c('HiTech', 'BFSI', 'Insurance', 'Retail', 'Ecomm', 'Media', 'Govt')
  for(i in 1:a) {
    b <- sample(vec1,1)
    return(b)
  }
}

n <- Vertical(5000)
```

I need the variable 'n' to return range of values (total 5000) which I am unable to achieve. Request for some help on it.
Thank-you.

Comment: shouldn't be `sample(vec1, i)` ,  `i` instead of `1`?

Comment: As PKumar mentions, you want to use `i`, and you might want to use `replace` too, `sample(vec1, i, replace=TRUE)`. Next you want `b` to be a list (`b <- list()`), so `b[[i]] <- sample(vec1, i, replace=TRUE)`. That way you can move the `return` statement outside the for-loop. Finally you may not want to use a loop, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: Thank-you PKumar and William, this explanation helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sample all the values together and put them in a matrix/data.frame.

```
Vertical <- function(nr, nc) {
  vec1 <- c('HiTech', 'BFSI', 'Insurance', 'Retail', 'Ecomm', 'Media', 'Govt')
  as.data.frame(matrix(sample(vec1, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr, nc))
}

Vertical(6, 3)

#         V1     V2        V3
#1      BFSI HiTech      Govt
#2 Insurance  Ecomm Insurance
#3     Media   Govt    Retail
#4     Ecomm  Ecomm      BFSI
#5    HiTech   Govt     Ecomm
#6      Govt   Govt    Retail
```

Comment: Thank-you Rounak, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
vec1 <- c('HiTech', 'BFSI', 'Insurance', 'Retail', 'Ecomm', 'Media', 'Govt')
b <- lapply(1:10, function(y) sample(vec1, y, replace=TRUE))
```